# How can I download over FTP all the XML files in a directory?

Tags: perl, file, ftp

How do I download all `*.xml` files from a folder on an FTP server using Net::FTP?

I saw that `glob()` would be the best way, but I cannot wrap my head around the logic.

I need to check if there are XML files in the folder. If not, wait 5 seconds, and check again. Once the files show up, then I need to download them and run them through a Java application which I already have working.

How can I monitor a folder for a specific filetype, and automatically `ftp->get` those files when they appear?

Comment: Are the xml files mutable? That is, do they undergo modification after the initial upload? If yes, then I am assuming that you need to download the updated file too. Correct?

Comment: It's really important to show the minimum code necessary to demonstrate what you tried and explain why it doesn't work, otherwise it sounds like you're asking us to write the code for you, not correct your mistake.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When I need to get a filtered listing of files on an ftp site I use [`grep`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/grep.html) with the `ls` method of Net::FTP.

warning, untested code:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

use Net::FTP;

#give END blocks a chance to run if we are killed
#or control-c'ed
$SIG{INT} = $SIG{TERM} = sub { exit };

my $host = shift;
my $wait = 5;

dbmopen my %seen, "files_seen.db", 0600
    or die "could not open database: $!";

while (1) {
    my $ftp = Net::FTP->new($host, Debug => 0)
        or die "Cannot connect to $host: $@";

    END { $ftp->quit if $ftp } #close ftp connection when exiting

    $ftp->login("ftp",'ftp') #anonymous ftp
        or die "Cannot login: ", $ftp->message;

    for my $file (grep { /[.]xml$/ and not $seen{$_} } $ftp->ls) {
        $ftp->get($file)
            or die "could not get $file: ", $ftp->message;
        #system("/path/to/javaapp", $file) == 0
        #   or die "java app blew up";
        $seen{$file} = 1;
    }
    sleep $wait;
}
```

Comment: Works perfectly, thanks! Now I just have to overcome a few problems that arose in the Java application...

Answer (score 0):

What about something like this?  This would of course be called every X seconds by your code.

```
my %downloaded;

sub check_for_new {
    # Get all files
    my @files = $ftp->ls;

    foreach $f (@files) {

        # Check if it is an XML file
        if($f =~ /\.xml$/) {

            # Check if you already fetched it
            if(!$downloaded{$f}) {

                if($ftp->get($f)) {
                    $downloaded{$f} = 1;
                } else {
                    # Get failed
                }

            }
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need to re-download xml files that might have changed then you also need to do a file compare to make sure that your local copy is in sync with the remote copy on the ftp server.

```
use Cwd;
use Net::FTP;
use File::Compare qw(compare);

my %localf;
my $cdir = cwd;

sub get_xml {
  for my $file ($ftp->ls) {
    ##Skip non-xml files
    next if $file !~ m/\.xml$/;

    ##Simply download if we do not have a local copy
    if (!exists $localf{$file}) {
      $ftp->get($file);
      $localf($file) = 1;
    } 
    ##else compare the server version with the local copy
    else {
      $ftp->get($file, "/tmp/$file");
      if (compare("$cdir/$file", "/tmp/$file") == 1) {
        copy("/tmp/$file", "$cdir/$file");
      }
      unlink "/tmp/$file";
    }
  }
}
```

I typed this out straight into the reply box so it might need a few touch-ups and error checking thrown in before being implemented. For the outer logic you could write a loop which establishes the ftp connection, calls this subroutine, closes the connection and sleeps for 'n' seconds.